# How can I change the type of data when I have a decimal point and a thousand comma in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

Please, I need to change the column "Sale" to a numeric format.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Sale':['9.455', '34,65%', '234.12', '32.6%','3,5%']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df.dtypes
```

I need to get the following result

```
[9455, 0.3465, 23412, 0.326,0.035]
```

Thank you very much
Hugo,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [pandas.to_numeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) + [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
values = pd.to_numeric(df.Sale.str.replace("[.%]", "").str.replace(",", "."))
result = np.where(df.Sale.str.contains("%"), values / 100, values)
print(pd.Series(result))
```

**Output**

```
0     9455.0000
1        0.3465
2    23412.0000
3        3.2600
4        0.0350
dtype: float64
```

The line:

```
values = pd.to_numeric(df.Sale.str.replace("[.%]", "").str.replace(",", "."))
```

converts the strings to numeric values after some pre-processing, then:

```
result = np.where(df.Sale.str.contains("%"), values / 100, values)
```

basically divides the numbers by `100` if it was a percentage value.

Answer (score 1):

With custom conversion:

```
import pandas as pd


def cast_floats(n):
    if n.endswith('%'):
        n = float(n.strip('%').replace(',', '.')) / 100
    else:
        dec_places = len(n[n.index('.') + 1:])
        n = float(n) * (10 ** dec_places)
    return n


data = {'Sale': ['9.455', '34,65%', '234.12', '32.6%', '3,5%']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Sale'] = df['Sale'].apply(cast_floats)
print(df)
```

The output:

```
         Sale
0   9455.0000
1      0.3465
2  23412.0000
3      0.3260
4      0.0350
```